# Unknown mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query and I keep on getting a syntax error. I ran it through different debugging tools and haven't found anything. Is tehre anything i'm missing.

**My Query**

```
 INSERT INTO futureposts
 (
    ID, 
    username, 
    postedby, 
    link, 
    message, 
    picture, 
    name, 
    caption, 
    description,  
    groups, 
    type
) 
VALUES 
('','1','CodeCompiler','CodeCompiler,'','','','','','','default','daily')
```

**The error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default','daily')' at line 1

Comment: You are missing a closing `'` at `'CodeCompiler`. There is also a mismatch between the columns and values (there are only 11 columns but 12 values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed ' code after **CodeCompiler** so change your query from

```
INSERT INTO futureposts (ID, username, postedby, link, message, picture, name, caption, description, groups, type) VALUES ('','1','CodeCompiler','CodeCompiler,'','','','','','','default','daily')
```

to

```
INSERT INTO futureposts (ID, username, postedby, link, message, picture, name, caption, description, groups, type) VALUES ('','1','CodeCompiler','CodeCompiler','','','','','','default','daily')
```

and also there is one extra column added in query , check it and remove extra column

Answer (score 0):

You missed ' (closing quote) after **CodeCompiler**

....VALUES ('','1','CodeCompiler','**CodeCompiler**,'','....

Also one change that you need to do that is you are giving 12 values to 11 column..I have checked personally in my phpmyadmin by creating same table.

So your final query will be

```
INSERT INTO futureposts (ID, username, postedby, link, message, picture, name, caption, description, groups, type) VALUES ('','1','CodeCompiler','','','','','','','default','daily');
```